# How to make opentracing work with opentelemetry

Tags: go, trace, opentracing, open-telemetry

My project is using OpenTelemetry for tracing in Go, and one of the lib I use only support tracing in Opentracing. I enabled the tracing in the lib directly and looks like it does not work. For this case of scenario, how can I make them work together?

Comment: Can you paste the code which you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OpenTracing bridge in `opentelemetry-go`. This will translate calls from the OpenTracing API into calls to the OpenTelemetry API.

See the doc here: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-go/blob/main/bridge/opentracing/doc.go